# Create new columns while appending to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with ~12,000 columns and a few hundred rows like the below:

```
Date     id1    id2    id3    id4    ...    id12000
1/4/16   100    78     103.5  15            35
1/5/16   100.5  78     104    16            37
1/6/16   99.5   78.5   104.5  16.5          37
1/7/16   100.1  77     104.2  13            37
1/8/16   100.3  76.5   104.2  13.5          33
1/11/16  99.8   77     103.7  13.5          34
...
5/1/17   101.1  82     103.6  12            33
```

Every day, I get a new dataframe that I need to add to this dataframe.  So, for example, I may get a dataframe for May 2nd that looks like the below:

```
Date     id1    id3    id4    id6    ...    id12100
5/2/17   100    103    12.5   15            100
```

But that dataframe will likely contain a few new ID's (columns) every single day, and it may also have a few of the ID's omitted that were previously there.

I would like my new dataframe to add columns every time there is a new ID, and fill all previous values of that column with `NaN`'s.  I'd also like any cells of ID's that were previously in the dataframe to be filled with `NaN`'s.  So, for example, the joining of the two above example dataframes would look like:

```
Date     id1    id2    id3    id4    ...    id12000   id12100
1/4/16   100    78     103.5  15            35        NaN
1/5/16   100.5  78     104    16            37        NaN
1/6/16   99.5   78.5   104.5  16.5          37        NaN
1/7/16   100.1  77     104.2  13            37        NaN
1/8/16   100.3  76.5   104.2  13.5          33        NaN
1/11/16  99.8   77     103.7  13.5          34        NaN
...
5/1/17   101.1  82     103.6  12            33        NaN
5/2/17   100    NaN    103    12.5          NaN       100
```

However, if I run this on a date that's already in the dataframe, I'd like to simply replace the old value with the new value.

I've been wrangling with this problem for a while now and can't quite figure out how I need to do it, between properly formatting the dates so that I can check whether there is a duplicate in the dataframe, to properly appending/joining/merging/etc. the old values with the new ones.  I have several different places where a generalized function would be really useful for me, so I'm hoping someone has had the same problem and has an elegant solution that I can use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first) be sure Date is your index in both dataframes:

```
print(df)

           id1   id2    id3   id4  id12000
Date                                      
1/4/16   100.0  78.0  103.5  15.0       35
1/5/16   100.5  78.0  104.0  16.0       37
1/6/16    99.5  78.5  104.5  16.5       37
1/7/16   100.1  77.0  104.2  13.0       37
1/8/16   100.3  76.5  104.2  13.5       33
1/11/16   99.8  77.0  103.7  13.5       34
5/1/17   101.1  82.0  103.6  12.0       33

print(df_new)

        id1  id3   id4  id6  id12100
Date                                
5/2/17  100  103  12.5   15      100
```

Use `combine_first` with Date as index:

```
df_out = df_new.combine_first(df)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
           id1  id12000  id12100   id2    id3   id4   id6
Date                                                     
1/11/16   99.8     34.0      NaN  77.0  103.7  13.5   NaN
1/4/16   100.0     35.0      NaN  78.0  103.5  15.0   NaN
1/5/16   100.5     37.0      NaN  78.0  104.0  16.0   NaN
1/6/16    99.5     37.0      NaN  78.5  104.5  16.5   NaN
1/7/16   100.1     37.0      NaN  77.0  104.2  13.0   NaN
1/8/16   100.3     33.0      NaN  76.5  104.2  13.5   NaN
5/1/17   101.1     33.0      NaN  82.0  103.6  12.0   NaN
5/2/17   100.0      NaN    100.0   NaN  103.0  12.5  15.0
```

Comment: I knew there would be some one-lined answer that I hadn't thought of yet.  This is great, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
     Date    id1   id2    id3   id4
0  1/4/16  100.0  78.0  103.5  15.0
1  1/5/16  100.5  78.0  104.0  16.0
2  1/6/16   99.5  78.5  104.5  16.5

In [44]: new
Out[44]:
     Date  id1  id3   id4  id6  id12100
0  1/6/16   11   11  11.0   11      111
1  5/2/17  100  103  12.5   15      100

In [45]: df.set_index('Date').append(new.set_index('Date'))
Out[45]:
          id1  id12100   id2    id3   id4   id6
Date
1/4/16  100.0      NaN  78.0  103.5  15.0   NaN
1/5/16  100.5      NaN  78.0  104.0  16.0   NaN
1/6/16   99.5      NaN  78.5  104.5  16.5   NaN
1/6/16   11.0    111.0   NaN   11.0  11.0  11.0
5/2/17  100.0    100.0   NaN  103.0  12.5  15.0
```